# Transformar texto para italico on hover!

Tags: html, html5, css3, css-hover, css-transições

Boas, eu tenho um paragrafo e quero que ele fique com `font-style: italic;` quando passo o rato por cima, que propriedades devo por no `:hover`?! Gostava que fosse uma transição de 0.3segundos

Comment: Infelizmente não tem como fazer transição com estilo de fonte.

Comment: pode usar javascript?

Comment: @MagicHat pode, desde que o script seja uma coisa simples para eu entender :D mas já tenho uma resposta para aquilo que queria , não precisa de se dar ao trabalho

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Não tem como, primeiro porque o único pseudo-elemento que existe para linhas é o `::first-line` e ele só vai pegar a primeira linhas, segundo o `font-style` diferente do `font-weight` não suporta valores numéricos para que seja feito uma transição entre o *não itálico* e o *itálico*.

### Mas nem tudo esta perdido

Você pode **simular** o itálico usando `transform` e se considerar parágrafos por `<p>` será possível, um exemplo funcional:

> **Nota:** para evitar o efeito de pulo (o tal bug), basta adicionar: `transform: skewX(0.001deg);`

```css
.container p {
    transform: skewX(0.001deg); /*evita o "efeito de pulo"*/
    transition: transform .3s ease-in-out;
}

.container p:hover {
    transform: skewX(-20deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
     <p>foo bar baz</p>

     <p>Hello World!</p>

     <p>Olá Mundo!</p>
</div>
```

Claro que isto não é itálico, se você tiver estilos nos parágrafos, como bordas ou background eles poderão ser afetados também, para evitar isto você pode adicionar `<span>` para cada paragrafo sem estilo e fazer assim por exemplo:

```css
.container p {
    background: #ccc;
    border-radius: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    padding: 5px;
}

.container p span {
    display: inline-block;
    transform: skewX(0.001deg); /*evita o "efeito de pulo"*/
    transition: transform .3s ease-in-out;
}

.container p:hover span {
    transform: skewX(-20deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
     <p>
         <span>foo bar baz</span>
     </p>

     <p>
         <span>Hello World!</span>
     </p>

     <p>
         <span>Olá Mundo!</span>
     </p>
</div>
```

---

### Tentando remover o blurry durante a animação

Infelizmente o titulo diz "tentando" porque não é algo 100% garantido, isso depende muito do hardware e do software que usa, o problema do efeito "blurry" nos textos é bem comum no Chrome, as técnicas (tentativas) que existem são:

### Usar `-webkit-font-smoothing: subpixel-antialiased;`:

Deve ficar assim:

```
.container p {
    transition: transform .3s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: subpixel-antialiased;
}
```

E no segundo exemplo:

```
.container p span {
    display: inline-block;
    transition: transform .3s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: subpixel-antialiased;
}
```

No entanto em computadores com driver de vídeo genérico provavelmente não vai funcionar como esperado, ou talvez não funcione de maneira alguma.

### Usar `transform: translateZ(0) ...`

Isso é um *hack*, ele por algum motivo no Chrome ajuda na aceleração de renderização, mas pelo que li em alguns casos funciona e em outros não, provavelmente depende do equipamento do usuário:

```
.container p:hover span {
    transform: translateZ(0) skewX(-20deg);
}
```

E no segundo exemplo:

```
.container p:hover span {
    transform: translateZ(0) skewX(-20deg);
}
```

Pode experimentar ambos, ainda sim como citei antes, provavelmente vai depender do equipamento (hardware e software).

---

**Nota:** @keyframes não resolve o problema do efeito *blurry*, o que ocorreu na resposta do hugo é que ele usou a fonte maior, se usar inicialmente `transform: skewX(0.001deg);`, antes da transição e colocar **`2em`** da fonte vai ficar quase idêntico ao `keyframes`

```css
#comtransform {
    font-size: 2rem;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: blue;
    transform: skewX(0.001deg); /*evita o "efeito de pulo"*/
    transition: transform .3s ease-in-out;
}

#comtransform:hover {
    transform: skewX(-20deg);
}
```

```html
<p id="comtransform">@keyframes</p>
```

Comment: Exactamente o que queria, obrigado ficou excelente =))

Comment: não tem como retirar o blur enquanto as letras inclinam?!

Comment: @Droopy infelizmente não, é o efeito da distorção e o tipo da fonte que causam isto.

Comment: Acabei de utilizar a tentativa de retirar o blurry mas infelizmente não funcionou :s

Comment: @Droopy editei a resposta, parece que adicionar `.container p {
        transform: skewX(0.001deg); ...` no elemento antes da animação/hover ajudou a melhorar o blur e até corrigiu um efeito de pulo que ocorria nas letras.

Comment: acabei de adicionar esse pormenor e corrigiu logo o blur, uma solução bastante inteligente =)) obrigado pela ajuda

Answer (score 1):

Fiz um teste usando `@keyframes` no lugar do `transition` E o resultado ficou até interessante, diminuiu bastante aquele buggizinho na altura do texto.

**Fiz um exemplo simples, veja o resultado.**

```css
p#anima {
    font-size: 2em;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: red;
    transition: all 300ms;
}
p#anima:hover {
    transform: skewX(-10deg);
}

p#key{
    font-size: 1.2rem;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: blue;
}
p#key-small{
    font-size: 0.6rem;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: blue;
}
p#key-big{
    font-size: 3rem;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: blue;
}
p#key:hover, p#key-small, p#key-big {
    -webkit-animation-name: example; /* Safari 4.0 - 8.0 */
    -webkit-animation-duration: 500ms; /* Safari 4.0 - 8.0 */
    animation-name: example;
    animation-duration: 500ms;
    animation-iteration-count: 1;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
p#key:not(:hover), p#key-small:not(:hover), p#key-big:not(:hover) {
    -webkit-animation-name: rever; /* Safari 4.0 - 8.0 */
    -webkit-animation-duration: 500ms; /* Safari 4.0 - 8.0 */
    animation-name: rever;
    animation-duration: 500ms;
    animation-iteration-count: 1;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

/* Safari 4.0 - 8.0 */
@-webkit-keyframes example {
    from   {transform: skewX(-3deg);}
    to {transform: skewX(-10deg);}
}
/* Standard syntax */
@keyframes example {
    from   {transform: skewX(-3deg);}
    to {transform: skewX(-10deg);}
}

/* Safari 4.0 - 8.0 */
@-webkit-keyframes rever {
    from   {transform: skewX(-8deg);}
    to {transform: skewX(-0deg);}
}
/* Standard syntax */
@keyframes rever {
    from   {transform: skewX(-8deg);}
    to {transform: skewX(-0deg);}
}
```

```html
<p id="anima">transition transform</p>

<p id="key">@keyframes</p>

<p id="key-small">@keyframes-small</p>

 <p id="key-big">@keyframes-big</p>
```

Comment: O 25% e o 50% podem ser removidos que o efeito será o mesmo, ao menos no Chrome.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimentoP. Nem tinha reparado rss, parece que só por ser @keyframe já atenua o efeito. Nesse caso seria melhor usar `from {transform: skewX(0deg);}`  `to {transform: skewX(-10deg);}` []´s

Comment: Exatamente Hugo! Somente from e to fica perfeito! - Só pra constar, efeito do "pulo" (o tal bug) foi removido com `transform: skewX(0.001deg);`, veja a resposta: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/264942/3635

Comment: Outra coisa que notei, o keyframe não removeu o blur, foi o tamanho da fonte que você usou que fez o efeito desaparecer, ou seja isso não resolve, se usar a fonte pequena o efeito blur ainda ocorre. Só pra avisar mesmo.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimentoP. na verdade o que mudou mesmo foi aquele pulinho que a fonte dava no início. O Blur não tinha melhorado muito mesmo não. Parece que a formatação do Estilo da font também pode afetar um pouco esse efeito de Blur indesejado. Parece que quando o Elemento já tem o `skewX` antes da animação acontecer o "saltinho" da fonte some!

Comment: Então uso, esse problema do *efeito blurry* ocorre devido a capacidade de aceleração grafica do hardware ou software, em monitores de retina, como Mac OSX é provavel que o blurry nem seja notado, mas em outros casos (efeitos css) mesmo com retina pode ocorrer, depende do efeito, depende do software e hard. Editei a resposta e adicionei um exemplo com `font-size: 2em`: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/264942/3635

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta mas basta adicionar `transform: skewX(0.001deg);` no p e o efeito blur deixa de se notar